# Install Virtualmin on Existing RedHat Linux server

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, redhat

I have a linux server which has Apache and MySQL running. I would like to install virtualmin on this server.

Will virtualmin erase my earlier configuration or it will take the existing configuration and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Virtualmin Installation FAQ](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/installation/faq):

> **What if I already installed Apache, Postfic, MySQL, Dovecot, etc. on my system?**
>
> If you installed from the OS standard repository for your OS,
>   everything should be fine. If you installed from any third party
>   sources, or from source, the installation will fail and things will go
>   badly. The install script cannot accommodate packages installed from
>   non-standard sources. It just isn't that smart.
>
> If you can re-install your OS, it is recommended that you start with a
>   freshly installed Grade A supported Operating System.

And this is from [Webmin FAQ](http://www.webmin.com/faq.html):

> **What effect will Webmin have on my existing configuration files?**
>
> Just installing Webmin will not cause any config file changes to be
>   made. When you start to use it, only the config files related to the
>   changes that you make in Webmin will be modified. For example, using
>   the Apache Webserver module would not effect your Sendmail
>   configuration.

(Virtualmin is an addition to webmin, not part of it, so sometimes webmin faq may be incorrect for virtualmin)

My advice based on the above:

- If you can, (even if that require some work), "start with a freshly installed Grade A supported Operating System".
- If you can't, make a backup of your system (at least, backup all your configuration files and the state of the installed packages) and install Virtualmin.